# Have a link that is imported in xml, clickable to execute a function

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Ok, here's the question, I have an xml doc that is being import into an AS3 file and then with .htmlText, appending it to a movie clip.  An example of what this looks like is:

```
<abstract><![CDATA[<p><strong>AEO Times Square</strong> Store Wins Prestigious SEGD Merit Award for Dynamic Environments <a href='event:OpenArticle1'>View Article</a></p>]]></abstract>
```

What I'd like to have happen is when I click that view article link that I can call a function passing in "OpenArticle1".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at [flash.events.TextEvent.LINK](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:link). There is an example in there too.